# Scala split string on whitespace excluding certain sections

Tags: string, scala, list

I want to split this string **"158.106.201.22 '-' '-' [08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000] 'GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1' 200 3293"**  into seven separate tokens
so that I end up with a list like:

```
List("158.106.201.22", "-", "-", "08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000]", "GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1", "200", "3293").
```

I tried using Scala `split()` method using empty space a separator but I end up spliting **"[08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000]"** and **"GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1"**
into separate tokens as they also include empty space, so I end up with something like:

```
List("158.106.201.22", "-", "-", "[08/Apr/2019:15:19:48", "+0000]", "GET", "/media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif", "HTTP/1.1", "200", "3293")
```

What is the best way to go about it?
Thanks!

Comment: `split()` allows you to provide the regular expression that will be used for splitting, so You can create a regex that will prevent splitting the words that You don't want to split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you don't like complex regexp:

```
val str = "158.106.201.22 '-' '-' [08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000] 'GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1' 200 3293"

val stage1 =  str.split("[\\[\\]\\']")
                  .map(_.trim)
                  .filterNot(_.isEmpty)

val result = stage1.dropRight(1) ++ stage1.last.split(" ")

println(result.toList)

//List(158.106.201.22, -, -, 08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000, GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1, 200, 3293)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use regular expression?

```
val str = "158.106.201.22 '-' '-' [08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000] 'GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1' 200 3293" 

val pattern = "([\\d\\.]+) ('-') ('-') (\\[.+\\]) ('.*') (\\d+) (\\d+)".r

val values = pattern.findAllIn(str) match {
   case matched => (1 to matched.groupCount).map(matched.group).toArray
}

values //Array("158.106.201.22", "'-'", "'-'", "[08/Apr/2019:15:19:48 +0000]", "'GET /media/2tSodgDfwCjIMCBY8h/200w_d.gif HTTP/1.1'", "200", "3293")
```